# is there any way to draw gridview without adapter but loop instead

Tags: android

i created topsis method and used loop for sorting the result 
like this :

```
for(int j=0;j<result.length;j++){
        for(int i=0;i<result.length;i++){
            if(alignment<result[i]){
                alignment=result[i];
            }
        }
        for(int k=0;k<result.length;k++){
            if(alignment==result[k]){
                System.out.println("number : "+(k));
                result[k]=-1;
                alignment=0;
            }
        }
```

and i want to put the result in gridview with images. is there any way to draw gridview without adapter but loop instead ?. i need to do this because if i use adapter, arrays will be drawn in sequence index like arr[0], arr[1],arr[2],etc, but i need to draw array in my sequence like arr[1],arr[2],arr[0], because i sorted the value of my array, so it changed the index of arrays.
thanks for the answers.

Comment: Question is unclear and GridView doesn't work without Adapter

Comment: @selvin if i use adapter, arrays will be drawn in sequence index like arr[0], arr[1],arr[2],etc, but i need to draw array in my sequence like arr[1],arr[2],arr[0], etc.

Comment: but you may reorder the array used as data for GridView in the way you want

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **yes** , you can use nested

[LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)

but is a **very bad** solution because you will lose recycler view system provided by

[RecyclerView.Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html)

[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) you can find more informations about RecyclerView implementation and it's benefits

[Here](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/) you can find a complete tutorial for implementation of a grid view using RecyclerView